# How to cross out a row of a spreadsheet (not to remove it !) using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When I execute this part of the code I would like to add a lign which is gonna cross out the row (incrementligne) or at list put the background of this row in red. Can we do it with google apps script?

```
 else if(statut=='sup'){
 deleteEvent(values[0][19]);
 ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("O"+incrementligne).setValue('Suppression OK'); 
 //add a lign here which is gonna a cross out the row
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked perfectly like this matching with my code:

```
 else if(statut=='sup'){

 deleteEvent(values[0][19]);
 var range=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(incrementligne,1,1,20)
 range.setFontLine('line-through')
 ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("O"+incrementligne).setValue('Suppression OK'); 

}
```

Comment: i had missed that function. Honestly not sure why it is separate from styles. came back to update my answer when i discovered it, looks like you found it first.

Answer (score 1):

setFontstyles() does not appear to support strikethu as an option
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontStyles(Object)

color on the other hand is supported:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String)

```
 else if(statut=='sup'){
 deleteEvent(values[0][19]);
 ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("O"+incrementligne).setValue('Suppression OK'); 
 ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(incrementligne,1,1 ss.getSheets()[0].getMaxColumns()).setBackground("red");
}
```

that should work, or at least be a starting point.

Edit: I missed `setFontLines('line-through')` using that inplace of `setBackground()` above will strike it through

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontLines(Object)

Comment: It has not work the way you did it for the entire row but I set the background to red just for the first cell of the row and it worked perfectly.

Comment: had a copy paste error. i think it will work for the row now.